# JS/jQuery merge array into another array's object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, merge

How can i add an array into an object of another array?

I have the following array:

`projectSave = ({ id: 1, name: 'Foo', desc: 'Bar', boards: {}, hotspots {} });`

I want to populate the **boards** and **hotspots** objects with data from seperate arrays.

`allBoards = {id: 'b1, name: 'Board 1'; id: 'b2, name: 'Board 2'}`
`allHotspots = {id: 'h1, type: 'link'; id: 'h2, type: 'link'}`

How can I populate data into an object of an array?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If an answer has solved your problem, be sure to up-vote it and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

First, allBoards should be:

```
allBoards = [{id: 'b1, name: 'Board 1'}, {id: 'b2, name: 'Board 2'}];
```

Everything between `{}` is considered the object. Inside the `[]` is what makes it an array of those objects. This makes it an array [] of objects {}. `allHotSpots` should be done in the same manner.

You'll have to loop through the arrays and recreate the objects for `projectSave` and add them to the `boards` and `hotspots` arrays.

```
for (var i = 0; i<allBoards.length; i++){
  projectSave.boards.push({id: allBoards[i].id,
                name: allBoards[i].name});

}
for (var i = 0; i<allHotspots .length; i++){
  projectSave.hotspots .push({id: allHotspots [i].id,
                type: allHotspots [i].type});
}
```

If you just try to set `projectSave.boards = allBoards`, you're just storing the reference, not a copy of the array. You may be better served creating a clone method if this is something you do regularly.

Comment: If allboards and allHotpots are always going to be the same length, you can do that in a single loop.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but noticed you have syntax errors in the code, strings weren't closed properly, semi-colons used as array delimiter instead of commas, and some properties should have been arrays instead of objects (I assume that was your intention), so I've corrected them as well.

And since you've also tagged this as jQuery, and in case your objects gradually gets more complex, here is a jQuery way to do it.

```
var projectSave = { id: 1, name: 'Foo', desc: 'Bar', boards: [], hotspots: [] };

var allBoards = [{id: 'b1', name: 'Board 1'}, {id: 'b2', name: 'Board 2'}];

var allHotspots = [{id: 'h1', type: 'link'}, {id: 'h2', type: 'link'}];


$.extend(true, projectSave, {
    boards: allBoards,
    hotspots: allHotspots
});

// Test
console.info(projectSave);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
projectSave.boards= allBoards;
projectSave.hotspots=allHotspots;
```

Comment: wow, spent an hour trying to make it work with .push or .concat... thanks a lot for the quick reply, it worked fine.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, doing it this way doesn't create a copy of the array in your object, but a reference to that array. You don't want to do that.

Comment: if you want to avoid copy problem which might arive due to unwilling changes into objects can be achieved with... The oiginal question doesnt say anything about copying it in... projectSave.boards= allBoards;
projectSave.hotspots=allHotspots; and then allBoards=null; allHotspots=null;

Comment: "How can i add an array into an object of another array?" tells me he wants an array's items added (copied) to another array.